# displaying the selected menu on boostrap drop down[only applies to first menu option&using attr()]

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to display the selected menu option using the bootstrap drop down.

I was able to select the first menu option and applied to the bootstrap drop down btn.

However, I cannot change the selected menu option after the first click.

I was pretty sure that using attr() was the problem.

So, I used each() but did not work either.

```
            <ul> 
                <li>.....</li>
                <li>.....</li>
                <li>.....</li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img height="25" src="img/flag_english.png" id="selected">
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item"><img value="jp" height="25" src="img/flag_japanese.png" class="language"></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"><img value="en" height="25" src="img/flag_english.png" class="language"></a>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                <li>
            </ul>
```

The following code worked for first option, which is `<a class="dropdown-item"><img value="jp" height="25" src="img/flag_japanese.png" class="language"></a>`

```
 $('.dropdown-menu a img').on('click', ()=>{
  let flag = $('.language').attr('src');
  console.log(flag);
  $('#selected').attr('src', flag);
})
```

I also tried using each()

```
  $('.dropdown-menu a img').on('click', ()=>{
  $('.language').each(()=>{
    let flag = $('.language').attr('src');
  })
})
```

But this did not work either.
How can I improve my code? or should I use different method?

Comment: I also tried to select the element by attribute name. `  $('img[class=language]').on('click', ()=>{
      let flag = $('this').attr('src');
      console.log(flag);
      $('#selected').attr('src', flag);
    })` But did not work either...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong it should be

```
 $('.dropdown-menu a img').on('click', function(){
     let flag = $(this).attr('src');
     console.log(flag);
     $('#selected').attr('src', flag);
 })
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just to quickly check with you, the point I was wrong were 1) ()=> 2)$('this') ? I thought function(){} could be written as ()=>{}